# Просмотр статических полей класса с помощью рефлексии типов.

Tags: c#, .net, design, рефлексия

класс Building используется как более гибкая альтернатива Enum'ам (Type safe enum pattern ).
Хотелось бы иметь возможность просматривать доступные статические поля в рантайме.
В моем решении каждый такой класс должен будет однообразно реализовать статический метод GetAllFields() , что мне не особо нравится.
Есть ли более элегантное решение данной проблемы , чем мое?

```
public abstract class ABase {  
  protected static IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllField(Type type) {
    var res = from x in type.GetFields()
              where x.IsStatic == true
              where x.IsPublic == true
              select x.GetValue(null);
    ABase obj;
    foreach(var item in res) {
        if(!(item is ABase))
            continue;
        obj = item as ABase;
        yield return obj;
    }
  }
}

public sealed class Building : ABase {
  public static readonly Building House = new Building();
  public static readonly Building Castle = new Building();

  public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllFields() {
    return GetAllField(typeof(Building));
  }

}
```

Comment: ладно видимо и правда нечего тут мутить воду . 
сделаю ABase.GetAllFields(typeof(Building)) по предложению @VlaD

Comment: Кстати, если Ваш метод `protected` то условие `if(!(item is ABase))` никогда не выполнится. Оно всегда `false`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
public abstract class ABase {  
  public IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllFields() {
    return GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static)
                    .Select(fi => fi.GetValue(null))
                    .Where(f => f is ABase)
                    .Cast<ABase>();
  }
}
```

Для статического метода трюк не сработает :(

Comment: погодите , как я вызову GetType() в статическом методе ? Type чего ? this то не существует .

Comment: @manchester: хм, да, сорри. И правда :) Сейчас подумаю ещё.

Comment: @manchester: Хорошо, а как вы собираетесь _вызывать_ этот метод? Напишите желаемый код.

Comment: хм , выше я привел свое решение . оно работает ...  
Building.GetAllFields();

Comment: @manchester: нет, не код функции, а код, который её вызывает.

Comment: эм , у меня пока нету кода . но чтото вроде этого будет 
    foreach(var i in Building.GetAllFields()){
        if (i.Name = someString)
             return i;
    }
где someString - поле из xml файла

Comment: Хм, если у вас будет _одна_ функция `GetAllFields`, ей неоткуда узнать то, что её вызывают для порождённого класса. Почему бы не сделать вызов в виде `ABase.GetAllFields(typeof(Building))`?

С другой стороны, вы пытаетесь сделать виртуальную функцию в статическом классе, это неправильно. Почему бы вам не перейти к instance-методам и полям?

А то вы, кажется, из статического класса и полей хотите сделать контейнер объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил эту задачу таким образом:

```
public abstract class ABase
{
  protected static IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllField<T>() => typeof(T)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(x => x.GetValue(null))
    .OfType<ABase>();

  public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public sealed class Building : ABase
{
  public static readonly Building House = new Building(nameof(House));
  public static readonly Building Castle = new Building(nameof(Castle));

  private Building(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }

  public static IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllFields() => GetAllField<Building>();
}
```

Вы можете обойтись без свойства `Name` в `ABase`, тогда метод `GetAllField<T>` может возвращать `IEnumerable<string>` для Вашего примера в комментариях.

А в моем примеры Вы можете проходить коллекию так:

```
foreach (var item in Building.GetAllFields())
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name); // Ваша логика.
}
```

**UPD:**
Можно автоматизировать создание read only полей, например так:

```
public abstract class ABase
{
  protected static IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllField<T>() => typeof(T)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(x => x.GetValue(null))
    .OfType<ABase>();

  protected static void Init<T>() => typeof(T)
      .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => x.SetValue(null, Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), x.Name)));

  public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public sealed class Building : ABase
{
  public static readonly Building House;
  public static readonly Building Castle;

  public Building(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }

  static Building()
  {
    Init<Building>();
  }

  public static IEnumerable<ABase> GetAllFields() => GetAllField<Building>();
}
```

Но не могу не согласить с `VladD` что лучше перейти к instance-методам.